# Unable to connect broker - kafka Tool

Tags: apache-kafka

I am facing below error message when i was trying to connect and see the topic/consumer details of one of my kafka clusters we have.

we have 3 brokers in the cluster which I able to see but the topic and its partitions.

[image]

Note : I have kafka 1.0 and kafka tool version is 2.0.1

Comment: You are going to have to post more details than this. What does your `server.properties` file look like? What are your consumer/producer details?

Comment: Does it work if you use `kafkacat` or `kafka-console-consumer` to read some messages?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt yes it does work with console producer and consumer with given same cofig.

Comment: @SimonClark what property you want from server.properties file?

Comment: If it works with those, then it sounds like an issue specific to the tool you're using maybe.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt i was able to use that tool for our other kafka server but not sure what is the issue, as well as broker and zookeeper ports are also accessible from my local machine i successfully did the telnet with configured ports.

Comment: Can you post `error.log`file in your KafkaTool installation folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For better visibility (even already commented the same in early days thread)
```

In my case, I got to know when I used Kafkatool from my local machine, tool tris to find out Kafka broker port which was blocked from my cluster admins for my local machine, `that is the reason I was not able to connect.`

#### Resolution:

Either ask the admin to open the port for intranet if they can, if they can not you can use tunnelling for your `testing purpose` or `time being` for your port.

Hope this would help a few.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue on my MacBook Pro. The tool was using "tshepo-mbp" as the hostname which it could not resolve. To get it to work I added `127.0.0.1    tshepo-mbp` to the `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: This solution also worked on Windows using Kafka in WSL. Get the exposed IP address of the WSL instance with the command `wsl -d "Ubuntu-20.04" hostname -I` and then include the reference in the hosts file located here: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Answer (score 5):

kafka tool is most likely using the hostname to connect to the broker and cannot reach it. You maybe connecting to the zookeeper host by IP address but make sure you can connect/ping the host name of the broker from the machine running the kafka tool.

If you cannot ping the broker either fix the network issues or as a workaround edit the host file on your client to let it know how to reach the broker by its name

Comment: Yes, this was the issue in my case.. when lookup into Kafkatool from my local machine find out that the Kafka broker port is blocked for my local machine. Resolution is either ask the admin to open the port if they can if not for testing purpose you can use the tunnelling for your port. hope they help few.

Answer (score 5):

To fix this issue, we need to change the server.properties file.

```
$ vim /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties
```

Here update the listeners value from

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

to

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

source:**https://medium.com/@Ankitthakur/apache-kafka-installation-on-mac-using-homebrew-a367cdefd273**

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Your answer is of great help!!

Comment: this resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 3):

This issue occurs if you have not set `listeners` and `advertised.listeners` property in `server.properties` file.

For Ex:
`config/server.properties`

```
...
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
...
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<public-ip/host-name>:9092
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When encountering problem on localhost:
edit `kafka/config/server.properties`:

change `zookeeper.connect` from `localhost` to external IP of local host.

Answer (score 0):

add to the file server.properties

advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092